# Regular expression matching all characters excluding spaces and newlines

Tags: regex

Below is the text for which I am trying to regular extract the samlresponse token value
Regex `name="SAMLResponse" value="(.*?)"`

```
name="SAMLResponse" value="PHNhbWxwOlJlc3BvbnNlIHhtbG5zOmRzPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwLzA5L3htbGRz
aWcjIiB4bWxuczpzYW1sPSJ1cm46b2FzaXM6bmFtZXM6dGM6U0FNTDoyLjA6YXNzZXJ0aW9uIiB4
bWxuczpzYW1scD0idXJuOm9hc2lzOm5hbWVzOnRjOlNBTUw6Mi4wOnByb3RvY29sIiB4bWxuczp4
bDpBdHRyaWJ1dGVWYWx1ZSB4c2k6dHlwZT0ieHM6c3RyaW5nIj5HV0ZDPC9zYW1sOkF0dHJpYnV0
ZVZhbHVlPjwvc2FtbDpBdHRyaWJ1dGU+PC9zYW1sOkF0dHJpYnV0ZVN0YXRlbWVudD48L3NhbWw6
QXNzZXJ0aW9uPjwvc2FtbHA6UmVzcG9uc2U+" />
```

I am not able to match the value between double quotes. Can someone please help

Comment: Help with what? What's the behavior you're expecting, and what (unexpected) behavior are you actually seeing?

Comment: i am not able to match the value

Comment: With the little information provided, you can do something like ```"SAMLResponse"[^>]+value="([^">]+)"``` https://regex101.com/r/E7FJKU/1 which would put the value in group 1. Or if this works for you ```"SAMLResponse"[^>]+value="\K[^">]*(?=[">])``` https://regex101.com/r/P6jNQd/1

Comment: @VishalChepuri The source looks like XML. Why do you not use a XML parser?

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression if you only want the value itself from your provided sample:

```
 value="([^"]*)"
```

Comment: instead of `.*`, at least use `.*?` or even better `[^"]*`!

Comment: Edit made. Thanks

Comment: without the exclaimation mark :)